# Is there a way to check if a GameObject has been destroyed?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm creating a game and i want to show a panel when the player is dead

I've tried different approaches but none seems to do what I want

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class DeadOrAlive : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject Player;
    public GameObject deadPanel;

    void Update()
    {
        if (!GameObject.FindWithTag("Player"))
        {
            deadPanel.SetActive(true);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Implement `OnDestroy` in a `MonoBehavior` attached your `Player` game object.

Comment: Why not enable/disable the player object, that way you can tell when the player is dead or alive and, you will also be able to reuse the object, rather than creating a new one and making the GC do a lot of work but, if destroying the object in necessary then to answer your question, you just compare the player object to null or use `OnDestroy`

Comment: @VincentBree Unless you're killing players every 200ms, the GC impact for this will be nominal.

Comment: @3Dave true, but IMO reusing the object is a little better than re-instantiating it, unless it's only used once, but sins its the player i would presume that it will be used a lot

Comment: okey so i tried to deactivate the player and it gets deactivated, now i tired 

```void Update()
    {
        if (!Player.activeInHierarchy)
        {
            deadPanel.SetActive(true);
        }
    }```

Comment: it still dont work

Comment: @SindreBerge try using `activeSelf`: `(!Player.activeSelf) { deadPanel.SetActive(true); }`

Comment: @VincentBree Still won't activate the panel, tried attaching the script to the player also did nothing :(

Comment: @SindreBerge if you are attaching it to the player then just do `if (!gameObject.activeSelf)` and remove the `GameObject Player` sins the game object to which the script is attached to **is** the player.

Comment: @VincentBree still no luck

Comment: I can see in the hierarchy it is deactivated

Comment: @VincentBree ```void Update()
    {
        if (!gameObject.activeSelf)
        {
            deadPanel.SetActive(true);
        }
    }```

Comment: @SindreBerge my bad. Don't attach it to the player, attach it to something else, forgot that `Update` won't run when the object is disabled, so you can't do `if (!active)`. Attach it to the panel do `!GameObject.FindWithTag("Player").activeSelf`, will write you the answer

Comment: @VincentBree already tried that..

Comment: it worked i just added it to a gameobject that is always active, the panel is deactivated at start maybe that was the problem

Comment: @SindreBerge that's good, i just posted the answer, had to open unity and test some stuff out, haven't used it in a while.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To check if a object has been destroyed, you should use MonoBehavior's `OnDestroy` like so:

```
// Attach this script to the player object
public class DeadOrAlive : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject deadPanel;

    void OnDestroy()
    {
        deadPanel.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

You can also instead of destroying the player object, set it to active/inactive, but to check if the player is dead or alive this way, you will need a separate object which checks the active state:

```
//Attach this to a object which isn't a child of the player, maybe a dummy object called "PlayerMonitor" which is always active
public class DeadOrAlive : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject deadPanel;

    void Update()
    {
        if (!GameObject.FindWithTag("Player"))
        {
            deadPanel.SetActive(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Haven't used unity in a while and forgot how weird it could get.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @VincentBree this is how I did it

```
  void Update()
{
    if (!Player.activeSelf)
    {
        deadPanel.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```